# Detect Jailbroken in iOS 11 or later

Tags: ios, cordova

Used "https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-jailbreak-detection" but still it didn't check the JAILBROKEN since Cydia and other options were bypassed in latest 11+ iOS versions

How to handle latest iOS using Cordova or in native code ?

Comment: i meant from 11.0  to 11.2.6.. I need the way to detect in the latest iOS version..

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Update 2021:**
You can use the extension on UIDevice from this article:
https://developerinsider.co/best-way-to-check-if-your-ios-app-is-running-on-a-jailbroken-phone/

I copied all code in here.

You can find the latest version of code on Github here (author is @vineetchoudhary):
https://github.com/developerinsider/isJailBroken/blob/master/IsJailBroken/Extension/UIDevice%2BJailBroken.swift

Whole code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIDevice {
    var isSimulator: Bool {
        return TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR != 0
    }
    
    var isJailBroken: Bool {
        get {
            if UIDevice.current.isSimulator { return false }
            if JailBrokenHelper.hasCydiaInstalled() { return true }
            if JailBrokenHelper.isContainsSuspiciousApps() { return true }
            if JailBrokenHelper.isSuspiciousSystemPathsExists() { return true }
            return JailBrokenHelper.canEditSystemFiles()
        }
    }
}
    
private struct JailBrokenHelper {
    static func hasCydiaInstalled() -> Bool {
        return UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "cydia://")!)
    }
    
    static func isContainsSuspiciousApps() -> Bool {
        for path in suspiciousAppsPathToCheck {
            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
    
    static func isSuspiciousSystemPathsExists() -> Bool {
        for path in suspiciousSystemPathsToCheck {
            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
    
    static func canEditSystemFiles() -> Bool {
        let jailBreakText = "Developer Insider"
        do {
            try jailBreakText.write(toFile: jailBreakText, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
            return true
        } catch {
            return false
        }
    }
    
    /**
     Add more paths here to check for jail break
     */
    static var suspiciousAppsPathToCheck: [String] {
        return ["/Applications/Cydia.app",
                "/Applications/blackra1n.app",
                "/Applications/FakeCarrier.app",
                "/Applications/Icy.app",
                "/Applications/IntelliScreen.app",
                "/Applications/MxTube.app",
                "/Applications/RockApp.app",
                "/Applications/SBSettings.app",
                "/Applications/WinterBoard.app"
        ]
    }
    
    static var suspiciousSystemPathsToCheck: [String] {
        return ["/Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/LiveClock.plist",
                "/Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Veency.plist",
                "/private/var/lib/apt",
                "/private/var/lib/apt/",
                "/private/var/lib/cydia",
                "/private/var/mobile/Library/SBSettings/Themes",
                "/private/var/stash",
                "/private/var/tmp/cydia.log",
                "/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.ikey.bbot.plist",
                "/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.saurik.Cydia.Startup.plist",
                "/usr/bin/sshd",
                "/usr/libexec/sftp-server",
                "/usr/sbin/sshd",
                "/etc/apt",
                "/bin/bash",
                "/Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib"
        ]
    }
}
```

Also, you need to add `cydia` in `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` key inside `Info.plist`. It's required for `canOpenURL` to work.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>cydia</string>
</array>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19058255)

Comment: @VinnyCoyne, you are totally right. I will update my answer :)

Comment: Do you think it's a good idea to have a string containing "cydia" in jailbreak check? After decompilation, you can easily find string "cydia" and change the returning value of the function on runtime. Or am I wrong?

Comment: It is returning `true` value on simulator iPhone 12 Pro, iOS 14.4

Comment: @KuvonchbekYakubov as far as I know, in Simulator you have access to the whole filesystem while on real device only to your application Sandbox.
Because of that on simulator you get this behavior.

Comment: Yes, I first checked simulator and jailbreak, thanks for response and update.

Comment: Did anyone tried this answer against liberty lite?

Answer (score 7):

In native code: You can use [DTTJailbreakDetection](https://github.com/thii/DTTJailbreakDetection), it is in Objective-C. If you use swift you need to use a [bridging header](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html).

Objective-C:

```
if ([DTTJailbreakDetection isJailbroken]) {

    // your code
}
```

Swift:

```
if DTTJailbreakDetection.isJailbroken() {

    // your code 
}
```

Comment: DTTJailbreakDetection uses almost identical code to the article in the accepted answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49195580/4086849)

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foundation

func isJailbroken() -> Bool {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    
    // Check for common jailbroken files or directories
    let jailbreakFilePaths = [
        "/Applications/Cydia.app",
        "/Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib",
        "/bin/bash",
        "/usr/sbin/sshd",
        "/etc/apt"
    ]
    
    for path in jailbreakFilePaths {
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: path) {
            return true
        }
    }
    
    // Check if Cydia app can be opened
    if let cydiaURL = URL(string: "cydia://package/com.example.package") {
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(cydiaURL) {
            return true
        }
    }
    
    // Check if the app is running in a sandboxed environment
    if let sandboxedPath = fileManager.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: nil)?.path {
        if sandboxedPath.contains("Library/MobileSubstrate") {
            return true
        }
    }
    
    // Check if the app is being debugged
    var info = kinfo_proc()
    var mib: [Int32] = [CTL_KERN, KERN_PROC, KERN_PROC_PID, getpid()]
    var size = MemoryLayout<kinfo_proc>.stride
    sysctl(&mib, 4, &info, &size, nil, 0)
    
    if (info.kp_proc.p_flag & P_TRACED) != 0 {
        return true
    }
    
    return false
}

// Usage
if isJailbroken() {
    print("Running on a jailbroken device.")
} else {
    print("Not running on a jailbroken device.")
}
```